# React use object value as state variable name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I want to use the value of one object to access state variable name

for ex:

```
const displayName = [
    {
        name: 'name', //Actually this is the state variable name 
        displayText: 'Name: '
    },
    {
        name: 'email',
        displayText: 'E-mail ID: '
    }
]

{
displayName.map(obj =>  (
    <p>{obj.displayText}</p>
    <div>
        {this.state.data.obj.name} //Here am facing issue. The state variables are: this.state.data.name and this.state.data.email. How to replace the obj.name here
    </div>
)
}
```

The state variables are: this.state.data.name and this.state.data.email. How to replace the obj.name here

If i give `{this.state.data.obj.name}` it's throwing an error like `name not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using variables for keys, you need to use square brackets

```
this.state.data[obj.name]
```

In square brackets notation, your solution requests:

```
this.state['data']['obj']['name']
```

Comment: ohh.. My bad.. i used this.state.data.[obj.name] After removing the dot it's working fine. Thanks man.

Comment: Are you sure that `this.state['data']['obj']['name']` is equivalent to `this.state.data[obj.name]` in this case though?

Comment: It is not, i wrote that first one you wrote, this.state['data']['obj']['name'], is equivalent of one written in question this.state.data.obj.name,